# Sinatra send_file gives 404 error when trying to store the file

Tags: ruby, http, get, sinatra

I am trying to download the file by simulating using postman

Response
`127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2021:03:54:47 -0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 - 4.4450`

Command
`send_file "#{filename}", :disposition=> "attachment", :filename => filename, :type => 'application/octet-stream'`

```
post '/' do
  fileSize = env['CONTENT_LENGTH'].to_i/1048576.0 # Converting to MB
  if params.has_key?(:file) && fileSize <= 1
    filename = params['file']["filename"]
    send_file "#{filename}", :disposition=> "attachment", :filename => filename, :type => 'application/octet-stream'
    puts ".......................FILE STORED........................."
  else
    puts "....................FILE NOT VALID........................."
  end  
end
```

Comment: It could be the file is not found. I would log out the filename var to check that's being set correctly in the query params. Failing that, I suggest forgetting about downloading a file for a moment and just see if you can post to that endpoint and get a 200 response. This will ensure it's a problem with downloading the file and not routing the request.

Comment: I am able to get the following file info
```>{"filename"=>"diet.txt", "type"=>"text/plain", "name"=>"file", "tempfile"=>#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210118-28539-1tmxeoh.txt>, "head"=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"diet.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n"}```

Comment: The file definately exists? And what is the path to the file?

Comment: yes file exists, path is /home/mayuresh/Downloads/diet.txt

Comment: how are you running the rails?  is it in a fake_root (via Apache, for instance)?

Comment: I am running it in myu local machine. https://localhost:4567/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your replys to my comments I can say the reason why this is not working is because the send_file command is not being supplied with the correct argments. According to these docs: https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Streaming/send_file - you must attach the file path as the first parameter and not just the file name.

Also, the location of the file (your downloads folder) may cause other problems. The file should be available from within your project directory somewhere, preferably in the `/public` folder.

To summarise:

- Move the file to the `/public` directory within your project.
- Prepend the file name with the path to where the file will be stored.